# how to align table in HTML email css

Tags: html, css

on normal desktop view, I want it to display in 2 columns, 
text on the left and image on the right. but on mobile view, I just want 1 column, also the image will be on top of the text.
I want to do this on HTML email. 
anyone know how to overwrite the table align left to right? my css below doesn't seem working, the color did change to red.
or other way of doing this?

```
<style type="text/css">
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .chunk {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  table.chunk:first-child{align:right!important;color:red!important;}
}
</style>

<table style="width: 600px;" class="main-table">
    <tr> 
    <td>

         <table align="left" style="width: 50%;" class="chunk">
            <tr><td>some text</td></tr>

         </table>

         <table align="left" style="width: 50%;" class="chunk">
            <tr><td>some image</td></tr>
          </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you really need to use `table`? Try using div instead and position accordingly

Comment: yes, I need to use table because this is for HTML EMAIL

Answer (score 0):

Tables are clunky and are typically not responsive to screen sizes.

A better way to do this would be by using a `div` with the styling `float: left`, and a `div` that you can `float: right`.

Then, whenever you do your media query for the smaller screen size, you can change the styling to remove `float`.

Comment: I need to use tables because this is for HTML EMAIL, for email, I don't think float will work

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a `table` to achieve this? You can use a container div and display it as `flex`. If you have the following code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="text">
      Here the text
  </div>
  <div id="imageDiv">
    <img id="image" src="http://www.socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

#container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#text{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

#imageDiv{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

#image{
  width: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #text{
    width: 100%;
  }

  #imageDiv{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6kuct7o/).

What I do on my code is to set a container as flex. Inside this container I have two divs in which you are going to set the text and the image.

Note that for screens of more than 480px I set the width of each div inside the container as 50% to be equals all the time.

When the screens are lower than 480px you have to set the width to 100% of each of those divs and set the `flex-wrap: wrap` because you want that the item that overflows will be on the next line.

**EDIT:** I noticed now that you want that the image will be on the top of the text for mobile screens. Then you have to change the orders of the divs on your media query.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #text{
    width: 100%;
    order: 2;
  }

  #imageDiv{
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6kuct7o/1/)**.